# Norms on polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials

Let $p_N (x) = d^N /dx^N ((x^2 -1)^N)$ for $N=0,1,2....$

Consider these polynomials as elements of the space $C[−1, 1]$ with
the norm $||.||_2$

Show that the inner product of $p_N$ and $p_M = 0$ if $N$ $\ne$$ M$

Find the norm $||p_N||_2$

I have been to to use IBP for the first part, but I'm unsure where to begin. I know how to find the innerproduct normally, but not of something like this. I also am confused by the second part, despite knowing that to find that norm, you do Pythagoras on the polynomial.

Comment: Using IBP and the fact that $[(x^2 - 1)^N]^{(N-1)} = 0$ for $x = \pm 1$, we can deduce that
\begin{align}
\langle p_N,p_M \rangle &= -\int_{-1}^1 [(x^2 - 1)^N]^{(N-1)} [(x^2 - 1)^M]^{(M+1)}dx
\end{align}
but I don't see where to go from there

Comment: As for the second part: the point is presumably to find the norm by calculating $\langle p_N,p_N \rangle$ in the same way that you calculate $\langle p_N,p_M \rangle$.

Comment: We can iterate IBP to get the formula
\begin{align}
\langle p_N,p_M \rangle &= (-1)^N\int_{-1}^1 (x^2 - 1)^N [(x^2 - 1)^M]^{(M+N)}dx.
\end{align}
It's clear that this is zero when $M + N$ is odd since we are integrating an odd function, but I don't see how to approach it in other cases

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But p_N(x) = $\frac{\mathsf d^N}{\mathsf dx^N} p_N(x)$, which is definitely not $(x^2-1)^N$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom how can you do IBP on that though?

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\langle p_N,p_M \rangle &= 
\int_{-1}^1 p_N(x)p_M(x)\,dx = 
\int_{-1}^1 [(x^2 - 1)^N]^{(N)} [(x^2 - 1)^M]^{(M)}\,dx
\\ & = 
\left. [(x^2 - 1)^N]^{(N-1)} [(x^2 - 1)^M]^{(M)}\right|_{-1}^1 - \int_{-1}^1 [(x^2 - 1)^N]^{(N-1)} [(x^2 - 1)^M]^{(M+1)}dx
\end{align}
$$

Comment: But what about the $d^N /dx^N $? Where has that gone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $p_N$ has  antiderivatives that vanish both at $-1$ and $1$. Assume (without loss of generality) that $N>M$;  we can iterate integration by parts to get
$$
\langle p_N,p_M\rangle=(-1)^N\int_{-1}^1(x^2-1)^N\,\frac{d^{M+N}}{dx^{M+N}}(x^2-1)^M\,dx=0,
$$
where the derivative is zero as the degree of $(x^2-1)^M$ is less than $N+M$.

When $N=M$, we need $$\frac{d^{2N}}{dx^{2N}}(x^2-1)^N.$$ The $2N$-derivative of a monic polynomial of degree $2N$ is the constant $(2N)!$. Thus (using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_%28-1%29%5E1+%28x%5E2-1%29%5EN+dx))
$$
\langle p_N,p_N\rangle = (-1)^N\int_{-1}^1(x^2-1)^N\,(2N)!\,dx=(-1)^N\,(2N)! \frac{\sqrt\pi(-1)^N\Gamma(N+1)}{\Gamma(N+\tfrac32)}=\frac{\sqrt\pi\,(2N)!\,N!}{\Gamma(N+\tfrac32)}
$$

Comment: Nice! The trick with degrees is what I was missing.

Comment: It is perhaps notable that your formula satisfies the recursion
$$
\langle p_{N+1},p_{N+1} \rangle = - \frac{2(N+1)^2}{N + \frac 32} \langle p_N,p_N \rangle
$$

Comment: How can you integrate that by parts?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. If $f(1)=f(-1)=0$, $$\int_{-1}^1 f'g=-\int_{-1}^1f\,g'.$$

Comment: You say $$\langle p_N,p_M\rangle=(-1)^N\int_{-1}^1(x^2-1)^N\,\frac{d^{M+N}}{dx^{M+N}}(x^2-1)^M\,dx=0,
$$ by parts, but how do you actually show this? I get that both the anti derivatives are equal to $0$ at $1$ and $-1$ but other than simply stating it, I don't know how to actually work it

Comment: Actually, I've seen what you have added, and understand why that differentiates to 0 and how that helps. But shouldn't $(x^2 -1)^N be inside the differentiating bit too?

Comment: If I'm honest, I just don't understand the whole line I said above. Why don't you have to multiply to get $(x^2 -1)^M+N$ before integrating? And why does that then $= 0$?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you don't understand. You have functions $f,g$. Denote by $g^{(n)}$ the $n^{\rm th}$ the derivative and by $f^{[n]}$ the $n^{\rm th}$ antiderivative (using the constant $0$). Assume also that $g^{(n)}(1)=g^{(n)}(-1)=0$ for all $n=0,\ldots,M-1$. Then $$\int_{-1}^1 f g = f^{[1]} g\left.\vphantom{\int}\right|_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1 f^{[1]}\,g^{(1)}=-\int_{-1}^1 f^{[1]}\,g^{(1)}=\int_{-1}^1 f^{[2]}g^{(2)}=\cdots=(-1)^N\int_{-1}^1f^{[N]}\,g^{(N)}.
$$
When $f=\frac{d^N}{dx^N}h$, $g=\frac{d^M}{dx^M}h$, you get from the above

Comment: *(continued)* $$
\int_{-1}^1f\,g=(-1)^N\int_{-1}^1h\,g^{(M+N)}=(-1)^N\int_{-1}^1h\,\frac{d^{M+N}}{dx^{N+M}}h.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your $p_n$-s are the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). I think you can do it by showing that $p_n$ satisfies the following differential equation:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}p_n(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right]+n(n+1)p_n(x)=0$$
And then use the differential equation to show orthogonality: let $n \neq m$. Then we have that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}p_n(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right]+n(n+1)p_n(x)=0$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}p_m(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right]+m(m+1)p_m(x)=0$$
Multiplying the first one by $p_m$ and the second one by $p_n$, we get that:
$$p_m(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}p_n(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right]+n(n+1)p_n(x)p_m(x)=0$$
$$p_n(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}p_m(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right]+m(m+1)p_m(x)p_n(x)=0$$
And subtract them:
$$p_m(x)p_n(x)[n(n+1)-m(m+1)]+p_m(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}p_n(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right]-p_n(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}p_m(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right]=0$$
Which can be rearranged:
$$p_m(x)p_n(x)[n(n+1)-m(m+1)]+[(1-x^2)(p_n'(x)p_m(x)-p_m'(x)p_n(x))]'=0$$
And integrating it from $-1$ to $1$:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}p_m(x)p_n(x)[n(n+1)-m(m+1)] \mathrm{d}x=0$$